# Java repaint image

Tags: java, image, swing, panel, repaint

I have a problem with my script; I want repaint a new image (another one is shown) when a button is pressed, but the button doesn't do anything...

```
ActionListener one = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel2.revalidate();
                panel2.repaint();
            }
        };

        btn1.addActionListener(one);



        JLabel test1 = new JLabel(myDeckOfCards.giveCardPlayer1().getImage());

        panel2.add(lab1);
        panel2.add(test1);
        panel2.add(pn5);
        panel2.add(pn1);
        panel2.add(btn1);
```

Comment: Actually, the button's ActionListener **does** do something -- it repaints your JPanel.  But you don't change the image being displayed, so repainting it will have no effect.  I agree with fd -- show your images in a JLabel's Icon.  The JPanel can hold this JLabel if desired.

Comment: i don't understand what you sugest. sorry for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `actionPerformed` you need to get hold of your `JLabel` and call `setIcon()` on it, passing in the new image.

There's a few ways to get the JLabel, one is to make sure you have a `final` variable declared to contain it somewhere in scope of your `actionPerformed` method, and another is to find it from inside the `panel2` (not recommended).

You could also pass it in to your `ActionListener` through a constructor if you declare a full-fledged class for that purpose.

**EDIT**:

```
final JLabel test1 = new JLabel(myDeckOfCards.giveCardPlayer1().getImage());

ActionListener one = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Get 'anotherIcon' from somewhere, presumably from a similar
        // place to where you retrieved the initial icon
        test1.setIcon(anotherIcon);
    }
};

btn1.addActionListener(one);

panel2.add(lab1);
panel2.add(test1);
panel2.add(pn5);
panel2.add(pn1);
panel2.add(btn1);
```

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand what you suggested can you show me an example?